# Как добавить в ribbon группу кнопок, которая будет отображаться постоянно, вне зависимости от выбранной вкладки?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

Как добавить в ribbon группу кнопок, которая будет отображаться постоянно, вне зависимости от выбранной вкладки?

Comment: Какой `ribbon` и откуда используете?

Comment: Делаю прогу с несколькими вкладками, в которых имеются контекстные кнопки. Нужно, чтобы в правой части этой панели располагались кнопки, которые не меняются в зависимости от контекста. Пробовал это сделать через toolbar, но сильно портится внешний вид.

Comment: Так у вас риббона на самом деле нет что ли? Кастомизируйте тулбар, чтоб не портил вид